# GTM Tagging Question - Only Unique item on two buttons is the url

Tags: triggers, google-tag-manager, tagging

I have two buttons with everything identical except the url. I would like to track clicks on each button separately. Any idea how I need to setup my trigger to get this to fire and track separately?

Answer (score 0):

Trigger? I would use the same trigger for both buttons, but then in tag config, I would reference a custom JS variable in the field where I want the URL to go.

The CJS variable would look something like this:

```js
function(){
  return {{Click Element}}.getAttribute("href");
}
```

Or try using the default click URL var. [image: the default click URL var]

If it doesn't work out, then add your actual html surrounding the buttons and we'll give you the actual code and selectors to use in the trigger.